# Vue.js: Add every new items to the top of the table

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I can't figure out how to add new items to the beginning of an array and then display new added item **always at the top of a table**.

`unshift` doesn't work for this purpose, due to the reason that it only adds **the first item to the beginning** and then no more.

I thought `slice` would be the way to go with `index--`, but it doesn't work the way I need it either.

Here is a [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/saitam/eqdpt0gw/19/) and here is the code:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   itemIndex: 0,
   items: [
     {"val": 1, "name": "John", "sex": "male"},
     {"val": 2, "name": "Maria", "sex": "female"},
     {"val": 3, "name": "Arnold", "sex": "male"},
    ]

  },
  methods: {
    testPush() { 
      this.items.push({"val": 456, "name": "Peter", "sex": "male"})
    },
    testUnshift() { 
      this.items.unshift({"val": 456, "name": "Peter", "sex": "male"})
    },
    testSplice() {
      this.itemIndex--;
      this.items.splice(this.itemIndex, 0,
        {"val": 456, "name": "Peter", "sex": "male"}
      );
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  background-color: none;
  transition: all 2s;
}

.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="testPush">PUSH</button>
  <button @click="testUnshift">UNSHIFT</button>
  <button @click="testSplice">SLICE TO INDEX -1</button>
  
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>index</th>
      <th>Value</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Sex</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody is="transition-group" name="fade">
      <tr 
          v-for="(item, index) in items"
          :key="item.val"
          >
        <td>{{ index }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.val }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.sex }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: In your code: `"Error: [Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: '456'. This may cause an update error.`

Comment: `unshift doesn't work for this purpose, due to the reason that it only adds the first item to the beginning and then no more.`. But unshift always put the new item on the top. What's your desired output ?

Comment: I have added an answer.

Comment: If I use `index` for key then the table row highlighting doesn't work. I need the newly added item to be highlighted at the top.

Comment: `:key="item.val"` is not unique, did you check `console` output, you will always get error

Comment: @saitam, I have made an update to my answer. Can you check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because of `:key="item.val"` 
in

```
<tr 
          v-for="(item, index) in items"
          :key="item.val"
          >
```

You are trying to add element with the same key. `:key` of `v-for` should be unique.

You can add `{"val": 456, "name": "Peter", "sex": "male"}` object only one time.

**Upd.**

Can you try to modify your `:key` like this?

```
<tr 
          v-for="(item, index) in items"
          :key="index + '|' + item.val"
          >
```

Comment: Thanks you sharing this solution. I implemented that on a table with rows and a radio button that does the selection. The selected value goes to the top.

Answer (score -1):

Add `this.$forceUpdate();` after the `unshift`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    itemIndex: 0,
    items: [{
        "val": 1,
        "name": "John",
        "sex": "male"
      },
      {
        "val": 2,
        "name": "Maria",
        "sex": "female"
      },
      {
        "val": 3,
        "name": "Arnold",
        "sex": "male"
      },
    ]

  },
  methods: {
    testPush() {
      this.items.push({
        "val": 456,
        "name": "Peter",
        "sex": "male"
      })
    },
    testUnshift() {
      this.items.unshift({
        "val": 456,
        "name": "Peter",
        "sex": "male"
      })
      this.$forceUpdate();
    },
    testSplice() {
      this.itemIndex--;
      this.items.splice(this.itemIndex, 0, {
        "val": 456,
        "name": "Peter",
        "sex": "male"
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  background-color: none;
  transition: all 2s;
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="testPush">PUSH</button>
  <button @click="testUnshift">UNSHIFT</button>
  <button @click="testSplice">SLICE TO INDEX -1</button>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>index</th>
      <th>Value</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Sex</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody is="transition-group" name="fade">
      <tr v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.val">
        <td>{{ index }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.val }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.sex }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```